# "Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:" after switch target platform

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, launch, target-platform

We have PDE application which we want migrate from 3.x to 4. version. For this we created new target platfrom. I got this TP in not complete state. Then I added neccesary .jars for solve ale eclipse and launch errors. But one launch problem remained. It is:

```
!SESSION Tue Jul 04 14:28:06 CEST 2017 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2017-07-04 14:28:06.334
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

But when I switch on our old TP, this problem not occurs, all is right. In both of them TP (I mean plugin in folder "plugins""and checked it in launch/debug configuration) I have plugins org.eclipse.equinox.launcher with version 1.2.0.
Please know someone what is problem? Thanks.

OSGI plugins:
[image]

Comment: EclipseStarter is in the org.eclipse.osgi plugin

Comment: Yes you are true. But I have this plugin in my plugins folder in my TP. And in launch config it is checked. For both TP I have OSGi plugins display above on the picture. On the old platform all is right but on the new TP for Eclipse 4 occurs the problem, how show log above.